# Excel - vlookup time, error #N/A

Tags: excel

On the `sheet2` I have the data:

```
1.1.2017 1:00:00    4
1.1.2017 2:00:00    7
1.1.2017 3:00:00    10
```

and that goes on for the rest of the year.

On the `sheet1`, in cell A1 is the selected month. 
Then in cell A2 is the formula:

`=DATE(2017,A1,1)+1/24`

In cell A3 is:

`=A2+1/24`

Formulas like in the cell A3 continue for the rest of the column A.

But when I try to use `VLOOKUP`,

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$8761,2,FALSE)`

I only get value for A2, for A3 and so on I get `#N/A`.

Actually I have the same file for the year 2016., same formulas and it works correctly. I only changed the year and now it doesn't work.

Comment: try `=match(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$B$8761, 0)`. If that gives `#N/A` then it can't find your value. Is that date you have in the column a recognized date format? It might be that one version of excel recognizes it and the other doesn't...

Comment: It has to do something with date format. I made the first file a month ago, for the year 2016. Now, I only changed the year and it doesn't work. I also used locking and protecting cells (I did unlock them now). I just dont know.

Comment: I'm presuming that on `sheet2`, there are 3 columns? (i.e. 1st column has **1.1.2017**, 2nd column has **1:00:00** and third column has **4**)

Comment: No, but your post made me remember how I did it. I copy - pasted values from sheet1 column A to sheet2 column A. I hope that'll work. It did work. It is connected with data format somehow. Thanks.

Comment: :) that's what I meant haha

Comment: It works here using your formula (and your format). Date format should have zero affect. The values must all be "real Excel dates".  What, exactly, is in A1 on the sheet that doesn't work?  When you copy/pasted from sheet1, you may also have needed to change the hard-coded year, and the sheet reference.